# How to describe xml which sets as editorExtras attribute in EditText

Tags: android

When I code xml and layout like the following, they cause Null Pointer Exception due to setContentView() worked by onCreate method in Activity.

【layout】

```
<LinearLayout>
  <EditText
    ...
    android:editorExtras="@xml/extra_data"
    ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

【res/xml/extra_data.xml】

```
<input-extras xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <extra android:name="hoge" android:value="huga"/>
</input-extras>
```

【Null Pointer Exception】

```
E  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E   at android.content.res.Resources.parseBundleExtras(Resources.java:1731)
E   at android.widget.TextView.setInputExtras(TextView.java:4068)
```

I think that the problem is in a parser which loads resource xml in OS.

But I won’t be able to fix that. So I’ll create xml which is loadable parser.

Incidentally, the above extra_data.xml behaves the following.

By my app, I extracted parseBundleExtras() which has a problem from Resources.java.

```
private void parseBundleExtras(XmlResourceParser parser, Bundle outBundle)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int outerDepth = parser.getDepth();
    int type;

    while ((type = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String nodeName = parser.getName();
        Log.d("TAG", "type:" + type + " name:" + nodeName);
    }
}
```

【logcat】

```
D/TAG: type:START_DOCUMENT name:(null) 
D/TAG: type:START_TAG name:input-extras
D/TAG: type:START_TAG name:extra
D/TAG: type:END_TAG name:extra
D/TAG: type:END_TAG name:input-extras
```

I suggest that because of the node name which refers to the first is null, at this time, it is Null Pointer Exception.

I couldn’t confirm the parse processing because of working at native side.

Above that situation, I’m looking for a way that how to describe xml so as not to be Null Pointer Exception in extra_data.xml.

If possible, I’d like to know the way that problems doesn’t occur even if I set xml as editorExtras attribute in EditText rather than that question.

Comment: Was this issue resolved ?

Comment: It did not solve it.
I gave up the development of keyboard products.

Comment: This bug appears to be documented and also not planned to be fixed, please see here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956242 I guess this feature is just not usable via XML and we're just gonna have to use code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that ：
When it was created:

```
public class ExtendEditText extends EditText {
    public ExtendEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Bundle bundle = getInputExtras(true);
        bundle.putString("hoge","huga");
    }

    public ExtendEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Bundle bundle = getInputExtras(true);
        bundle.putString("hoge","huga");
    }

    public ExtendEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Bundle bundle = getInputExtras(true);
        bundle.putString("hoge","huga");
    }
}
```